# What is this tracking circle called as?

Tags: movement, gameobject

I don't know what the circle in the image below used for changing directions and movements of a character is called. Can anyone provide me anything related to it? I want to include it in my game.

[image: This screenshot is from game 'missiles']

Answer (score 1):

It's a **virtual joystick**.

Whether or not you should use one as a controller is debatable, as discussed [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25612/using-a-virtual-joystick-for-a-game).

> - You can't see/feel where the joystick is pointing when you are using    it.
> - You can't feel where the 'edge' of the joystick is - meaning, you    can't know when you are reaching the maximum in any direction
> - You don't always know when you're pressing the joystick. You can    accidentally miss pressing it and not know, because you can't feel
>     the joystick under your finger.

Comment: Thanks  your answer was very useful. I got what i needed! I'll sure research more before using it.